# Expand a bash variable, but not the variables it contains

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scripting, variable-expansion

I need to be able to expand a variable into exactly what is it declaration string is rather than bash expanding other variables in its declaration like it normally does.

```
variable=word
var="this variable contains a $variable"

echo ????
```

I need a command that results in: "`this variable contains a $variable`"
...rather than: "`this variable contains a word`"

The variable declaration must remain the same because it needs to expand normally in all other situations. So I can't use single quotes in the declaration.

Comment: Would just using single quotes work for you, or do you have a script in which the variable is already in double quotes?

Comment: @RayToal unfortunately no, I can't change the variable declaration. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: This is impossible. When you execute `var="blah blah blah $variable", `$variable`  is expanded before being assigned to `var`. (You can see this easily; changing the value of `variable` doesn't affect `var`.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is effectively impossible, because inside double quotes, `$variable` is substituted by the contents of that variable **at the time of definition**.
At the time you're printing it, the expansion has long happened (as can be seen using `set`).

If you cannot change the definition **at all**, the only thing you can **try** is to revert the substitution:

```
echo ${var/"$variable"/'$variable'}
```

This will replace every occurrence of what `$variable` currently holds by the string literal `$variable`, so in your example it would replace all occurrences of `word` with `$variable`, regardless of whether it was defined that way or not.
Also, as Jasper correctly pointed out, this relies on the fact that `$variable` does not change between the definition and the printing of `$var`.

Now, if you actually **can** change the definition, but only want the expansion to still happen, there are a number of options:

1. Use single quotes in the definition, and `eval` when printing.

   ```
   var='this variable contains a $variable'
   # later
   eval "echo "'"'"$var"'"'    # -> this variable contains a word
   echo $var                   # -> this variable contains a $variable
   ```

   Admittedly, this is rather cumbersome.
   Also note that variable expansion happens at the time of printing rather than at the time of definition (actually, just at whatever time `eval` run).
2. Use two different variables.

   Instead of writing `eval "echo "'"'"$var"'"'` every time, you could just store its result in a variable and use that, right?

   ```
   var='this variable contains a $variable'
   varX="$(eval "echo "'"'"$var"'"')"
   # later
   echo $varX      # -> this variable contains a word
   echo $var       # -> this variable contains a $variable
   ```

   Or, of course just copy the definition of `$var` and replace `'` by `"`... but that's boring. :P

   Here the expansion happens at the time of defining `$varX`.
3. Use an array instead of two different variables.

   This is really interesting, because for arrays `$var` is equal to `${var[0]}`, so you can do

   ```
   tmp='this variable contains a $variable'
   var=("$(eval "echo "'"'"$tmp"'"')" "$tmp")
   # later
   echo $var           # -> this variable contains a word
   echo ${var[1]}      # -> this variable contains a $variable
   ```

   This is probably as close as it gets to what you want, but you will still have to change the definition.

Comment: updated the question to rule this solution out, I can't change the variable declaration

Comment: I see, yeah what I'm looking for in this question is impossible. I will have to work out another solution using single quotes as suggested before, but it won't be relative to this question as I posed it so I'll be accepting this answer.

Comment: @Jasper Yes, it relies on the fact that the variable didn't change, but how does the problem not occur? `$variable` inside double quotes is substituted at the time of definition, regardless of whether `$variable` changes afterwards or not.

Comment: My bad, it would seem I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 3):

you can use single quote:

```
variable=word
var='this variable contains a $variable'
echo var
```

Comment: updated the question to rule this solution out, I can't change the variable declaration

Comment: If you cannot change the variable declaration, just forget the issue.  $variable is being substituted in variable declaration.  **bash(1)** variable substitution is done in var="this variable contains a $variable" as it is double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use sed

```
variable=word
var="this variable contains a $variable"
var=$(echo "${var}" | sed "s/\${variable}/${variable}/g")
```